# How can we highlight a full word and a partial word in php?

Tags: php, regex, algorithm

Below is my code, I want to highlight a full word and a partial word. The code below just highlights the *full* word but not the *partial* word.

**For example :**

```
$text = "this is a very famouse poem written by liegh hunt the post want to impress upon the importance";
```

AND

```
$words ="very written hu want impor";
```

I want output like below :-

"this is a **very** famouse poem **written** by liegh **hu**nt the post **want** to impress upon the **impor**tance";

Function that i have created for it:-

```
function highlight($text, $words) {
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
    if(!$m)
        return $text;
    $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';
    return preg_replace($re, '<b style="color:white;background-color:red;border-radius:2px;">$0</b>', $text);
}
```

Comment: Remove `\b` if you do not want to match whole words. See https://ideone.com/cMXG0M

Comment: if $words string contain both partial and full words then  i want to highlight both partial and full word highlight.

Comment: So, what good are the word boundaries then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop struggling with regular expressions when you have inbuilt functions in php.
Same functionality with pure php. without using regular expression, by ignoring case sensitive.

```
<?php

 $words = "very written hu want impor";
 $words = explode(' ', $words);

function hilight($text, $words){
   foreach ($words as $value) {
    $text = str_ireplace($value,'<b style="color:white;background-color:red;border-radius:2px;">'.$value.'</b>',$text);
   }
  return $text;
}

$text = "this is a very famouse poem written by liegh hunt the post want to impress upon the importance";
echo hilight($text, $words);

?>
```

[image]